# Javascript RegExp test

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to verify a pattern of `5 characters - 5 characters - 5 characters` with Javascript and I want it to fail if there are more or less than 5 characters between dashes. My test is as follows:

```
var patterns = new RegExp("[2-46-9A-DF-HJKMP-RTVW-YX]{5}-[2-46-9A-DF-HJKMP-RTVW-YX]{5}-[2-46-9A-DF-HJKMP-RTVW-YX]{5}","gi");

if(patterns.test(fkLicense) == true) {
    alert('good');
} else {
    alert('bad');
}
```

My issue is, no matter what I set the value of fkLicense to, the test fails. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want those character groups to represent

Comment: "No matter what I set the value of fkLicense to, the test passes." - is that true? Empty string? The number 1? What if it's 11111-11111-11111?

Comment: The groups represent the characters that are valid.

Comment: that code works for me.

Comment: I am not sure whether an empty string would be true, because I am checking for an empty string. No, 11111-11111-11111 returns false.

Comment: jrahhali mybad, everything fails.

Comment: that is a very strange regex, what does a fklicense look like, explain in english? If its just 5 char - 5 char - 5 char that will be quite a bit different than what you have

Comment: I think you need to examine what your character groups (`[...]`) are representing, seriously. numbers 2-4, 6-9, letters a through d, f through h, k, j, m, or p through r... you even do w-z and then explicitly also state x right after.

Comment: does `patterns.test('22222-22222-22222')` fails too?

Comment: I figured it out, I was getting the value of fkLicense from an input field, and in my code I wasn't using fkLicense.value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to match, but the problem is that you need to [**anchor**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) your regular expression and it's alot easier to use a regular expression literal here instead ...

```
var patterns = /^ .... $/i
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/387241)

Comment: Your resolution works also. My issue was caused by how I was getting the value of fkLicense.

Comment: I don't understand how anchoring would make any different. Without anchoring it might match strings with extra stuff at the front and end, but it should still match the strings the OP wants to match. Why is this the accepted answer since the OP him/herself said the problem was a typo?

Comment: I agree OP did state it was a typo and fixed it but also OP does state `I want it to fail if there are more or less than 5 characters between dashes`, if you remove the anchors it returns true for strings like `22222-22222-2222222`